# Is there an english translation of Delignes "La conjecture de Weil pour les surfaces K3."?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

The title is pretty self explanatory: I'm looking for an english translation of Delignes inventiones paper "La conjecture de Weil pour les surfaces K3."

Anyone know if such a thing exists?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. Just google "[deligne proof of weil conjecture for k3 surfaces](https://www.google.com/search?btnG=1&pws=0&q=deligne+proof+of+weil+conjecture+for+k3+surfaces)" and click on the first (or second) link.

Comment: It's a good thing the answer was yes. In general proving non-existence of translations is much harder.